# How can i convert double? to double. Math.Sqrt operations

Tags: c#

i would like to ask for some help to this code right below this question... i am encountering some error that says "Argument 1: cannot convert double? to double". How can i fix this what should i add?

```
private void Calculate(string newOperator = null)
    {
        double? result = null;
        double? first = numbers[0] == null ? null : (double?)double.Parse(numbers[0]);
        double? second = numbers[1] == null ? null : (double?)double.Parse(numbers[1]);

        switch (@operator)
        {
            case "÷":
                result = first / second;
                break;
            case "×":
                result = first * second;
                break;
            case "+":
                result = first + second;
                break;
            case "-":
                result = first - second;
                break;
            case "√":
                result = Math.Sqrt(first);
                break;
            case "SIN":
                result = Math.Sin(first);
                break;
            case "COS":
                result = Math.Cos(first);
                break;
            case "TAN":
                result = Math.Tan(first);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you think will happen if you run `first * second` when one or both of the terms is `null`?

Answer (score 1):

you can access the value of a nullable type with `.Value`, if that's what you mean.

for example, `Math.Sqrt(first.Value)`

---

edit:

I didn't think this needed to be said, but I'll add this on thanks to the urging of a commenter:

as nullable types *can be null*, you should check if your double? actually has a value before using it.

for example, `first.HasValue` will return a bool that tells you if the nullable has a value or not.

Comment: yeap it worked :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarkAnthonyZaraspe No, it did not work. You will get an exception when `first` is null and you use `.Value` on it

Comment: good catch. fixed the typo.

also, yes the use of a nullable type here seems strange and very possibly error prone; you should check for null and handle appropriately. 

I suspect the nullable isn't needed here, but that's rather out of the scope of the question.

Comment: added the extra info anyway, better safe than sorry I suppose...

Answer (score -1):

You can convert `double?` to `double` like this:

```
double ConvertNullableDoubleToDouble(double? input)
{
    return input.Value;
}
```

This is a bit messy since input could be `null`. Really, what you should do is add a default value or something to make it super-explicit how to handle null values.

```
private static double ConvertNullableDoubleToDouble(double? input, double? defaultIfNull = null)
{
  if (input != null && input.HasValue)
    return input.Value;
  else if (defaultIfNull != null && defaultIfNull.HasValue)
    return defaultIfNull.Value;
  else
    throw new Exception(string.Format($"Unable to parse input {input}"));
}
```